# angular bind click event on a from ajax response

Tags: jquery, angularjs, events, binding

I'm developping my first angular app. In my controller, I do an ajax request which returns an HTML content. I put this content in my view with binding.

I want to bind a function on click event from all a in my HTML content. How do that without jQuery ?

Here my code :

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://my-url',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  data: {}
})
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.content= $sce.trustAsHtml(data.myContent);
    // Here I want to bind a function on click event of a inside myContent
})
.error(function() {
})
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: In your markup add an ng-click="eventHandler()" and in the .success() call $scope.$apply() so any bindings etc are updated. Also try setting a timeout on scope.$appy() if it is not working.

Comment: or you can have it always bound but have a variable on the scope which represents whether or not to execute it

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have no control on the html content response. So, I can't add ng-click ....